# how can send photo to user with pyTelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

code:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    bot.send_photo("1267203280",message.file_id)
```

error:

```
File "/home/Mrcpp1/test.py", line 23, in handle_docs_photo
    bot.send_photo("1267203280",message.file_id)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'file_id'
```

I search about it bot can't find answer
and I tried different methods but can't solve it
how can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`send_photo`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_photo):

```py
try:
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, open("path_to_your_photo", 'rb'))
except Exception as error:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str(error))
```